# print from n down to 0 with a for loop in c++

Tags: c++

I need this code to output 
3
2
1
Blastoff!

I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong with relating i to userNum in the for loop. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int userNum = 0;
   int i = 0;

   userNum = 3;

       for(i = 1; i <= userNum; i--) {
       cout << i << endl;
       cout << "Blastoff!" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps time to learn how to use the debugger

Comment: Shouldn't you start from userNum till 0?

Comment: Move blastoff to after the loop

Comment: What compiler/IDE are you using?  @EdHeal has the right answer.  You need to be able to troubleshoot simple things like this.  With more details we can tell you how to fire up your debugger.

Comment: I solved it. I had to set i equal to userNum for the first part of the for loop and then set i > 0 in the middle part of the for loop

Comment: part of my problem also is that I am using a built in IDE in a website called Zybooks to do my homework, so it doesn't have a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I fix your code, please try it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int userNum = 0;
   int i = 0;

       for(i = 3; i > userNum; i--) {
       cout << i << endl;
   }

   cout << "Blastoff!" << endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: oops, i thought he need the 0 haha, well thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing your homework by yourself. :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  int userNum = 3;
  for(i = userNum; i > 0; i--) {
     cout << i << " ";
  }
  cout << "Blastoff!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing here is to understand termination condition in for loop.
Here you should see that it compares 3>0, 2>0, 1>0, and 0>0 (Evaluates to False) therefore only going in the loop 3 times. Your userNum variable makes no sense to me, as you are not even getting input from the user. So I just put arbitrary hard-coded values in for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int userNum = 0;
  for(int i = 3; i >userNum; --i)
    {
      cout << i << " ";
    }

  cout << "Blast Off!" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```